# how to solve React.js problem with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I want to use setInterval in react but at the beginning of the program it counts faster than it should , var i increased by 2 every second , how can i change my code to solve this?

```
import React from "react";

var i = 0;

function Light() {
  setInterval(function() { 
    i++;
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);

  return <div>
    <h3>This Is a Text!</h3>
  </div>
}

export default Light;
```

Comment: Please format your code block.

Comment: You gave only 1 second for setInterval, what is your expected output?

Comment: Every time this component renders it will start a new interval timer. It is not unusual for components to render multiple times; if you want a one-time "thing" it should go in a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use useState and useEffect. Indeed these methods are used to keep data and logic between rerenders, which was not the case in your implementation

```js
function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(()=> {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      setIndex(index+1)
    }, 1000)
  },[index])

  return <h3>{index}</h3>
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```